# os.environ['PATH'] doesn't match echo %PATH%

Tags: python, ffmpeg, path, environment-variables, jupyter-notebook

I have `PATH` variable set for `ffmpeg` which I tested with CMD command `echo %PATH%` but Python's `os.environ['PATH']` doesn't contain registry of it.  I'm using Jupyter notebook on Windows.

Comment: Are you aware of how environment variables propagate between processes? They are not system-global variables! That said, please provide exact steps to reproduce the problem and the expected and actual output.

Comment: What is the difference?  Is there no `PATH` environment variable in python?     Try printing the whole of `os.environ`, an issue with Windows is that (unlike other operating systems) environment variable names are not case sensitive but the keys to a Python dictionary are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting session solved the problem. Somehow on my work computer reboot wasn't needed for environment variable to take effect.